# Specify MultipleActiveResultSets in SQL CLR Trigger

Tags: c#, .net, triggers, sqlclr, sql-server-mars

I have a SQL CLR Trigger that has a number of `SqlDataReader` calls in it (among other things), where in the production system users are getting errors like

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "MyTrigger":
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
>   ...

however I am unable to reproduce this in my test env. I am considering setting `MutltipleActiveResultSets=true`, but of course there is no connection string to define in the CLR Trigger (or is there...) - so is it possible to set `MARS` to true somewhere here, or do I need to keep looking for an alternate solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the in-process Context Connection, then no, you cannot enable MARS. This restriction is documented.

If you want / need a MARS connection, then you need to use a regular / external connection. That will require setting the Assembly to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. It also means that you are not working "in process" and so won't have access to the the session that is executing the Trigger.